# how to bind multiple port with multiprocessing when using tornado

Tags: python, multiprocessing, port, tornado

My python version is 3.4, my tornado version is 4.3.
I have 2 servers, and they have to share some datas during runtime, my code is like this,

```
from tornado.web import gen, asynchronous, RequestHandler, Application
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop


class HelloHandler(RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        self.write('hello')
        self.finish()


class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        self.write('main')
        self.finish()


helloApp = Application([
    (r'/hello', HelloHandler),
])

mainApp = Application([
    (r'/main', MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello_server = HTTPServer(helloApp)
    hello_server.bind(8881)
    hello_server.start()
    # hello_server.start(0)
    main_server = HTTPServer(mainApp)
    main_server.bind(8882)
    main_server.start()
    # main_server.start(0)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

It works, but when I tried to support multiple processes by using server.start(0), I recived an error:  '**OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use**',  I used different ports already (8881, 8882). How does this happen?
And how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start(n)` only works with a single server. To use more than one, you must use `bind_sockets`, `fork_processes`, and `add_sockets` separately (example adapted from http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/tcpserver.html):

```
from tornado.netutil import bind_sockets

hello_sockets = bind_sockets(8881)
main_sockets = bind_sockets(8882)
tornado.process.fork_processes(0)
hello_server = HTTPServer(helloApp)
hello_server.add_sockets(hello_sockets)
main_server = HTTPServer(mainApp)
main_server.add_sockets(main_sockets)
IOLoop.current().start()
```